# jQuery ajax works in Chrome, but not in Firefox or Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox, safari

I implemented ajax request with `jQuery`. This is the code:

```
//initialize value, nameValue, emailValue

$.ajax({
  url: "getPOST.php",
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    'id': value,
    'name': nameValue,
    'email': emailValue
  },
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

The code works fine in chrome, but it fails in Safari and in Firefox. I've seen some answers to this question, but they are 6 or more years old. What could be the fix for this problem?

EDIT: By fail I mean that on php side, nothing gets stored in database when run on Firefox or Safari, but it works as expected in Chrome. There is no error messages in console. The request in Safari is shown in red, and it didn't sent any data.

[image]

I inspected the post data in Firefox and they are as they should be. No errors there. Although the request is painted in red. This is how it looks. An error on the jQuery side?

[image]

I am using this code to send data to my server, before directing user to the PayPal payment page.

jQuery code. Hope I didn't delete to many braces.

```
 // JavaScript Document
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      //you can now use $ as your jQuery object.



    //real stuff here
    $(".submit-link").click(function(e){
     var value=$.trim($(".url-submit").val());

     if(value.length>0){
     value = encodeURIComponent(value);
     var nameValue=$.trim($(".name-submit").val());
     var emailValue=$.trim($(".email-submit").val());

    if(nameValue.length>0){nameValue = encodeURIComponent(nameValue);}
    if(emailValue.length>0){emailValue = encodeURIComponent(emailValue);}


     $.ajax({
       url: "getPOST.php",
       type: 'POST',
        data: {"id":value,"name":nameValue, "email":emailValue},
       success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
        }


    //go to link in href now
     });
        }else{
    var $urlSubmit = $('.url-submit');
      $urlSubmit.addClass('invalid');
      setTimeout(function(){
        $urlSubmit.removeClass('invalid');
      },500);

    e.preventDefault();
        }
    });


    //some other stuff

    });
```

Comment: When you say it fails, what happens? There's nothing at all wrong with the snippet you've shown that would cause inconsistencies between browsers

Comment: Added an edit..

Comment: Open up the developer tools in the browsers where it fails and see if there are any error messages in the console. If you see any, please share them as they'll help diagnose the problem. Edit: Just saw you said it fails on the PHP side. Can you echo/log out what the post vars look like. You can also inspect the network tab to see what values were sent to the server.

Comment: @MadhuMagar you deserves a downvote for that, none, single, double ['id'] ` works just fine

Comment: first set the data type you are sending application/json , second use JSON.stringify on your data before sending it

Comment: @Dymos Nothing gets echoed out when using Safari or Firefox. Chrome echoes as expected.

Comment: @Ryad.iv but I don't need json, plain POST is ok. Is this a must?

Comment: in all cases use JSON.stringify on the data to be sent as text and if you are sending the data from a form you can use the jquery serialize

Comment: You don't need to use json stringify and application/json! `x-www-form-urlencoded` is just fine and that is what jquery will do for you

Comment: if the requests are shown in red, that's usually fairly good indicator that something isn't going right ;) check all the usual things like PHP error log (you are logging errors in dev, right?). Try the request with `curl` or something similar. If nothing stands out, might be time to share a reduced case of your JS & PHP code that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got to long for a comment but try excluding jquery and try simple xhr/fetch to see if it works (maybe you will get a other understandable error if you try fetch)

```
fetch('getPOST.php', {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
   body: 'id=0&name=bob&email=bob%40localhost'
}).then(res => console.log(res))
```

(safari don't have fetch so try in firefox)

The only thing i can thing of is that you are posting cross origins... Are you posting to the same domain? Must be a network error/restriction cuz your code is valid

Comment: The server I am using isn't DNS connected yet, so I just type in the IP address.

Comment: perhaps try not to redirect you post to paypal if it's done in same request

Comment: This is the reason for strange behaviour. Thanks mate!